# Split column values into multiple columns with

Tags: mysql

With an SQL query, my current table like *Example A*, how can I take a table like in *Example B*:

Example A

```
+----------+------------+
| quantity | product    |
+----------+------------+
| 3        | apple      |
| 1        | orange     |
| 4        | kiwi       |
| 2        | banana     |
+----------+------------+
```

Example B

```
+----------+------------+
| quantity | product    |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | apple      |
| 1        | apple      |
| 1        | apple      |
| 1        | orange     |
| 1        | kiwi       |
| 1        | kiwi       |
| 1        | kiwi       |
| 1        | kiwi       |
| 1        | banana     |
| 1        | banana     |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what this does mean. Can you explain more, please ?

Comment: If the quantity for apple is 3, he/she wants to have 3 row with 1 apple at the end.

Comment: Yes，correct. I want to split all value to one.

Comment: I dont think this is possible in single query. Can be done using cursor or stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a big table to generate a number and join on that generated number sequence. 'AnyBigTable' can be a table or query that returns at least the amount of records as the largest product quantity you have. So for your example data, it only needs 4 records to support the kiwi.

```
select
  1 as quantity,
  product
from
  YourTable t
  inner join 
    (select 
      @rownum := @rownum + 1 as num
    from
      AnyBigTable x
      , (select @rownum := 0) r
    ) n /* n.num contains numbers from 1 to rowcount of x */
  on /* Join the number table to get that amount of rows for the product */
    n.num <= t.quantity 
order by product
```

See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd210e/3

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a procedure for this.

```
delimiter //
create procedure split_tableA()
begin
 declare a_quantity int;
 declare a_product varchar(100);
 declare x  int;
 declare done int;
 declare cur cursor for select quantity,product from tableA ;
 declare continue handler for not found set done=1;
 set done = 0;
 open cur;
 data_loop: loop
   fetch cur into a_quantity,a_product;
   if done = 1 
    then leave data_loop; 
   end if;
   SET x = 1;
   while x<=a_quantity do
     insert into tableB (quantity,product) values (1,a_product);
     SET  x = x + 1; 
   end while;
 end loop data_loop;
 close cur;
end ;//

delimiter ;
```

Here are some test

```
mysql> select * from tableA;
+----------+---------+
| quantity | product |
+----------+---------+
|        3 | apple   |
|        1 | orange  |
|        4 | kiwi    |
|        2 | banana  |
+----------+---------+

mysql> select * from tableB;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call split_tableA();
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.32 sec)

mysql> select * from tableB;
+----------+---------+
| quantity | product |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | apple   |
|        1 | apple   |
|        1 | apple   |
|        1 | orange  |
|        1 | kiwi    |
|        1 | kiwi    |
|        1 | kiwi    |
|        1 | kiwi    |
|        1 | banana  |
|        1 | banana  |
+----------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding variables and functions, cross join the table against some other table(s) to generate a range of rows (where the range is greater than the max value of quantity).

For example

```
SELECT 1, current_table.product
FROM current_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
WHERE current_table.quantity > (units.aCnt + 10 * tens.aCnt)
```

This has 2 sub queries each generating a range of numbers from 0 to 9, which are manipulated to give 0 to 99.